# Blender not letting me add keyframes for camera

Tags: camera, keyframes

I am trying to add keyframes for my camera but blender is saying that it is failing to set keyframes, here's a screenshot. Does anyone know how to fix this?

The error message is "*Keying set failed to insert any keyframes*"

[image: screenshot showing alert message]

[image]

Comment: hello please share your file (only camera if necessary): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Your error message implies you have a keying set enabled and the camera location is not in that keying set.  Can you left click the button for _keying_ in the time line and screenshot the popup that appears?

Comment: @MartyFouts I just added another screenshot

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear.  in the timeline, in top bar, on the right side, there is a button called _Keying_ (right after _Playback_).  If you press it a menu pops up.  Can you grab a screenshot of that menu.

Comment: @MartyFouts I added it

Comment: As I expected, you have a Keying set _Button Keying Set_ enabled.  if you click the 'x' next to that you should be able to add keyframes for the camera again.  When a keying set is enabled, only keys from that set can be added.

Answer (score 2):

> Keying set failed to insert any keyframes

This error is usually because you are trying to key an element not included in your [keying set](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/keyframes/keying_sets.html), or it is included but not initialized correctly.

A good practice before setting any keying set is to first set keyframes on all the values you need to key, and then use the keying sets to make sure you don't over key stuff you don't want to.

In your case, I'd suggest to either remove your keying set entirely by clicking the <kbd>X</kbd> icon, or spend time setting your keys without keying set and then add back a keying set. Also maybe use a less restrictive one like `Available` or `Character`.

You can find the keying set in the `Time Editor` header, or in `Properties Editor` > `Scene` tab > `Keying set` panel, or in the viewport by pressing <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>.